# Why I can't see my files inside a docker container?

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, docker

I'm a Docker newbie and I'm trying to setup my first project.
To test how to play with it, I just cloned one ready-to-go project and I setup it ([Project repo](https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony)).
As the guide claims if I access a specific url, I reach the homepage. To be more specific a symfony start page.

Moreover with this command

```
docker run -i -t testdocker_application /bin/bash
```

I'm able to login to the container.

My problem is if I try to go to the application folder through bash, the folder that I shared with my host is empty.

I tried with another project, but the result is the same.

Where I'm wrong?

Here some infos about my env:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Docker version 1.8.3, build f4bf5c7

Config:

```
application:
    build: code
    volumes:
        - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
        - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
    tty: true
```

Comment: Does your docker user have access to `/symfony` and `/logs/symfony` on the host machine? Often it's a permissions issue.

Comment: How can I check this thing? my folders have 755 permissions in host and the owner is the same user that launch the docker-compose (it also belongs to docker group as stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a `docker-compose.yml` file but are running the image with `docker`. You don't actually need docker-compose to start a single container. If you just want to start the container your command should look like this:

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd)/symfony:/var/www/symfony -v $(pwd)/logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs testdocker_application /bin/bash
```

To use your `docker-compose.yml` start your container with `docker-compose up`. You would also need to add the following to drop into a shell.

```
stdin_open: true
command: /bin/bash
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a `docker-composer.yml` inherited from the project and I run the container with `docker-compose up -d`. I tried with your first command and I'm able now to see the folder content and I added the two lines in the application config. So, If I want to see my shared folder in bash, should I always use this syntax? And If I have 50 folders shared, should I list all of them in command? Thank you for you help